# applying a series of conditional functions to a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I need to apply a series of conditional functions to several columns on a data.table.
I did it manually but was a lot of typing, how can I make this into a simpler function?

```
dt_cases[
  , `:=`(cc_app_gt7 = fifelse(cc_app_min > 7, 1, 0),
         cc_app_gt30 = fifelse(cc_app_min > 30, 1, 0),
         cc_app_gt60 = fifelse(cc_app_min > 60, 1, 0),
         cc_app_gt90 = fifelse(cc_app_min > 90, 1, 0),
         cc_app_gt120 = fifelse(cc_app_min > 120, 1, 0),
         cc_app_gt180 = fifelse(cc_app_min > 180, 1, 0),
         cc_app_gt365 = fifelse(cc_app_min > 365, 1, 0),
         cn_gt7 = fifelse(cn_app_min > 7, 1, 0),
         cn_gt30 = fifelse(cn_app_min > 30, 1, 0),
         cn_gt60 = fifelse(cn_app_min > 60, 1, 0),
         cn_gt90 = fifelse(cn_app_min > 90, 1, 0),
         cn_gt120 = fifelse(cn_app_min > 120, 1, 0),
         cn_gt180 = fifelse(cn_app_min > 180, 1, 0),
         cn_gt365 = fifelse(cn_app_min > 365, 1, 0),
         daysdiff_gt7 = fifelse(days_diff > 7, 1, 0),
         days_diff_gt30 = fifelse(days_diff > 30, 1, 0),
         days_diff_gt60 = fifelse(days_diff > 60, 1, 0),
         days_diff_gt90 = fifelse(days_diff > 90, 1, 0),
         days_diff_gt120 = fifelse(days_diff > 120, 1, 0),
         days_diff_gt180 = fifelse(days_diff > 180, 1, 0),
         days_diff_gt365 = fifelse(days_diff > 365, 1, 0))
]
```

Creating a vector with the new column names was easy:

```
thresholds <- c(7, 30, 60, 90, 120, 180, 365)
cols_pref <- c("cc_app", "cn", "daysdiff")
eg <- expand.grid(cols_pref, thresholds)
cols <- paste0(eg$Var1, "_gt", eg$Var2)
```

And also a vector of the columns where I'm going to apply the *fifelse* function:

```
vars <- c("cc_app_min", "cn_app_min", "days_diff")
```

But how can I mix all these things up to the *fifelse* function without typing so much?

Thanks!

Comment: Using `for` loop and `set` should be straightward and easy to customize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to use the 'eg' and 'cols'

```
library(data.table)
dt_cases[, (cols) := Map(function(x, y) +(x > y), 
            mget(as.character(eg$Var1)), eg$Var2)]
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how the solution works because now I'll like to, instead of giving a 1/0 to the true/false condition response, give it a "column name_GT_threshold" to the true condition response and "column name_LTE_threshold" to the false condition response. Is it possible to include this inside the Map?

Comment: No worries... I was able to make it: dt_cases[, (cols) := Map(
  function(x, y, z) fifelse(x > y, 
                         paste0(z, "_GT_", y),
                         paste0(z, "_LTE_", y)), 
            mget(as.character(eg$Var1)), eg$Var2, eg$Var1)]

Answer (score 2):

Here an approach that uses `lapply` and `setNames`:

```
library(data.table)
thresholds <- c(7, 30, 60, 90, 120, 180, 365)
cols_pref <- c("cc_app", "cn", "daysdiff")
dt_cases[,lapply(.SD, function(x) as.data.table(
                                     setNames(lapply(thresholds,
                                                     function(y) as.integer(x > y))
                                              ,thresholds)))
         ,.SDcols = cols_pref]
```

The names come out a little different because I take advantage of the built in column renaming from `data.table`.